# How to get nested query string parameter

Tags: javascript, html

The use case is to land on a page with a URL looking like this -
`http://localhost:3000/track?url=https://somewebsite.com/?968061242&lang=EN&sign=daff4be265096eb31aca5c986ac51c6c&source=api_wrapper`

I tried the following to get the query params,

```
let search = window.location.search;
let params = new URLSearchParams(search);
let resp = params.get('url');
console.log("resp => ", resp);
```

but the output I get is only up to `https://somewebsite.com/?968061242`
How I can also get the nested params as part of the same get method call?

Comment: Some of those characters are supposed to be URL encoded. Specifically, the second `?` is supposed to be `%3F` and the `&` that is not part of the query structure should be `%26`. Since the string you're trying to parse is malformed in this case, the parser is having trouble with it. (If you copied it from the browser's url bar, it's only displayed like this for your convenience. You'll need to encode it for it to work with the standard functions.) (Those "nested" params probably got parsed out as un-nested. You can likely look up their values using their keys as normal.)

Comment: got it, so before passing the param as a Query String, I need to encode it, and after fetching need to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Use urlencoding api of JS

Example:

```js
const url = `http://localhost:3000/track?url=${encodeURIComponent('https://somewebsite.com/?968061242&lang=EN&sign=daff4be265096eb31aca5c986ac51c6c&source=api_wrapper')}`

let search = new URL(url).search;
let params = new URLSearchParams(search);
let resp = params.get('url');
```